# Create a Vaadin Request Handler that handles the request before Spring Security gets a chance

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, vaadin

So we're aiming to migrate an application from Thorntail to Spring Boot.

One issue is that we're using Vaadin 8 for legacy reasons.

The app provides password-less login suport (as in login-by-link).

Now vaadin is a single-page framework, so we've split off the `/login` and `/passwordless` login options into Vaadin UIs of their own s.t. we can configure

```java
override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .httpBasic().disable()
        .formLogin().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login").anonymous()
            .antMatchers("/passwordless/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/vaadinServlet/UIDL/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/vaadinServlet/HEARTBEAT/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .logout()
            .addLogoutHandler(logoutHandler())
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?goodbye").permitAll()
            .and()
        .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login"))
}
```

Unfortunately, we'll have to support the old links that have already been distributed as well for backwards-compitability. And the old login-links were set up as

```
/#!passwordless/<login-token>
```

Which means even if we add a filter, we won't be able to distinguish the request from any other request to `/`.

Currently, we see no other option than to allow unauthenticated requests to `/` and manually redirect to the login page if the user is not authenticated, which is very ugly.

Can we somehow define a vaadin request handler (that DOES have access to the vaadin location `/#!passwordless/<login-token>` and therefore can read the `<login-token>` and redirect to `/passwordless/<login-token>`) before Spring-security can redirect us to `/login`?

Answer (score 0):

As the hash is not included in the HTTP request, it's impossible to have it on the server before a response has been sent.

Perhaps you could configure a filter that intercepts all requests to `/`. If the user is authenticated, it does nothing. Otherwise, it either redirects to another page that has some JavaScript, or then it returns some JavaScript directly, that checks the hash and does a client-side redirect either to `/login` or to `/passwordless/<login-token>`.

I guess this is basically what you describe as ugly, but as long as that filter is in place, it shouldn't be an issue.

Edit: An alternative, if the hash is forwarded to the login page, you could include a piece of JavaScript on the login page itself, that checks for the presence of the hash and redirects appropriately.